# Reactive form - Cross fields validation (Single mesage based on group field's value)

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form as below:

```
this.newReporterform = this.formBuilder.group({
  rptrTitle: formBuilder.group({
    reporterTitle: new FormControl(),
    reporterTitleNV:new FormControl()
  }, {validator: this.bothEmptyValidator}) ,
  rptrfirstName: formBuilder.group({
    reporterFName: new FormControl(),
    reporterFNameNV:new FormControl()
  }, {validator: this.bothEmptyValidator}) , 
  rptrmiddleName: formBuilder.group({
    reporterMName: new FormControl(),
    reporterMNameNV:new FormControl()
  }, {validator: this.bothEmptyValidator}) ,
  rptrLastName: formBuilder.group({
    reporterLName: new FormControl(),
    reporterLNameNV:new FormControl()
  }, {validator: this.bothEmptyValidator}) ,
```

});

HTML sample view of the above is as below:

```
<form [formGroup]="newReporterform"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
  <div class="col-sm-12 ">                        
                      <div class="form-group" formGroupName="rptrfirstName" >
                          <span>First Name / Given Name </span>
                          <div class="input-group" >                            
                          <input type="text" class="form-control " [(ngModel)]="reporterFName" formControlName="reporterFName">                       
                          <select class="form-control col-sm-3" style="font-size:13px;"  [(ngModel)]="reporterFNameNV" formControlName="reporterFNameNV">                             
                              <option value="0" >Pls select</option>
                              <option value="1" >Option1</option>
                              <option value="2" >Option2</option>
                              <option value="3" >Option3</option>
                              <option value="4" >Option4</option>                              
                            </select>                            
                      </div>
                      <div class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.controls.rptrfirstName.controls.hasError('bothEmpty')">
                        Please enter information in one of the above fields.
                  </div>
                   </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">                        
                      <div class="form-group" formGroupName="rptrmiddleName">
                          <span>Middle Name </span>
                          <div class="input-group">                            
                          <input type="text" class="form-control " [(ngModel)]="reporterMName" formControlName="reporterMName">                       
                          <select class="form-control col-sm-3" style="font-size:13px;" [(ngModel)]="reporterMNameNV" formControlName="reporterMNameNV">
                              <option value="0">Select</option>
                              <option value="1">MSK</option>
                              <option value="2">ASKU</option>
                              <option value="3">NASK</option>
                              <option value="4">UNK</option>
                            </select>                            
                      </div> 

          <div class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.controls.rptrmiddleName.controls.hasError('bothEmpty')">
                        Please enter information in one of the above fields.
                  </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
</form>
```

Please note - my validator function:

```
 bothEmptyValidator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => { 
    const ValuesArray= Object.values(fg.controls)   
    let field1 = ValuesArray[0].value;
    let field2 = ValuesArray[1].value;    
     field1 === null && field2 === null  ? { bothEmpty: true } : null  
    }
```

My validator function works well in geting the values of two controls inside formgroups like **rptrfirstName/rptrmiddleName..etc**and works fine for all such sub-formgroups of the main form ..however I am stuck at displaying error " Please enter information in one of the above fields.", whichThrows error like  `_co.newReporterform.controls.rptrfirstName.controls.hasError is not a function`...

Note ** IT IS A COMMON ERROR SHOULD BE DESPLAYED AT THE BOTTOM OF THE TWO CONSECUTIVE FIELDS.**
Below  is the sample display of the field groups:

[image]

Is there a way to implement the error **without mentioning/getting into individual controls inside form-group( of two fields?)** (I mean, handling at the form-group level)

Any help on this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
ASJ

**-----UPDATE-------**
 Form submission results values 'undefined' in form-controls. hence validator msg is not getting flashed to UI.

[image]

Comment: the error is about the formGroup, so must be `newReporterform.controls.rptrfirstName.hasError('bothEmpty')` -remove the "controls"

Comment: thanks...error  on console is resolved...however validation error is not flashed to the UI...object has values as 'undefined' (image attached to the original post),,,have tried to initialize as reporterFName: new FormControl('')...still not working...

Comment: you has severals error in your code, I write a response that I hope help you

Comment: have incorporated recommended  the changes in the code...Thank you so much....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the validator to send the error to the formGroup you need to actually return the value, I am not sure whether you left it out when you copied it, but just in case, your code should be:

```
bothEmptyValidator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => { 
  const ValuesArray= Object.values(fg.controls)   
  let field1 = ValuesArray[0].value;
  let field2 = ValuesArray[1].value;    
  return field1 === null && field2 === null  ? { bothEmpty: true } : null; 
}
```

That said, you also need to access the formGroup which you assigned the validator to when calling the `hasError` method, not the control list. Try the following instead:

```
<div class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.controls.rptrfirstName.hasError('bothEmpty')">
  Please enter information in one of the above fields.
</div>
```

Notice the only difference is `hasError` belongs to `rptrfirstName` instead of `rptrfirstName.controls`.

Comment: Thanks David!...yes now error is resolved..however error msg is not getting displayed to the form....performing submit with no data fills the formcontrol values 'undefined'...So have performed the initialzation as  rptrfirstName: formBuilder.group({
        reporterFName: new FormControl(''),
        reporterFNameNV:new FormControl('')
      }, {validator: this.bothEmptyValidator}) ...still unable to get msg to frontend. Am attaching screen shot to the original post.

Comment: I see in the screenshot you are printing the value of the form, can you instead print the value of `this.newReporterForm`, and check this two things: 1. Is the attribute `valid` equal to true? 2. If you go inside of the controls array, then rptrfirstName for instance, is this one valid? Is the `errors` attribute equal to null?

Comment: Hi David....Check  1 ->  attribute valid equal to "true" / Check  2 -> errors: null. Issue with validatorFn??....have tried a single fileld inside formGroup with "Required" validator and repeated above checks...Values of properties are correct and error is flashed to UI...

Comment: Your validator is not working then. Did you add the return statement as I mentioned in my first comment? Otherwise it could be the fact that you are comparing them against null, try undefined instead, or maybe just `return !field && !field2 ? {bothEmpty: true} : null;` so you also check against an empty string.

Comment: It works perfectly, with your modified return expression. Thank you so much ..!

Comment: Thank you for thinking about testing it with the required validator yourself, that sped up finding the solution a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Newbie, you has a lot of errors in your code.

First, NOT use [(ngModel)], you are using reactiveForms. You can use new FormGroup and not FormBuilder, so your form is like

```
this.newReporterform = new FormGroup({
  rptrTitle: new FormGroup(
    {
      reporterTitle: new FormControl(),
      reporterTitleNV: new FormControl()
    },
    this.bothEmptyValidator
  ),
  rptrfirstName: new FormGroup(
    {
      reporterFName: new FormControl(),
      reporterFNameNV: new FormControl()
    },
    this.bothEmptyValidator
  ),
  rptrmiddleName: new FormGroup(
    {
      reporterMName: new FormControl(),
      reporterMNameNV: new FormControl()
    },
    this.bothEmptyValidator
  ),
  rptrLastName: new FormGroup(
    {
      e: new FormControl(),
      reporterLNameNV: new FormControl()
    },
    this.bothEmptyValidator
  )
});
```

And the form like

```
<form [formGroup]="newReporterform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="col-sm-12 ">
        <div class="form-group" formGroupName="rptrfirstName">
            <span>First Name / Given Name </span>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control "  formControlName="reporterFName">
                <select class="form-control col-sm-3" style="font-size:13px;"   formControlName="reporterFNameNV">
           <option [ngValue]="null" >Pls select</option>
           <option value="1" >Option1</option>
           <option value="2" >Option2</option>
           <option value="3" >Option3</option>
           <option value="4" >Option4</option>                              
        </select>
            </div>
            <div class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.get('rptrfirstName').hasError('bothEmpty')">
                Please enter information in one of the above fields.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" formGroupName="rptrmiddleName">
            <span>Middle Name </span>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control " formControlName="reporterMName">
                <select class="form-control col-sm-3" style="font-size:13px;" formControlName="reporterMNameNV">
          <option [ngValue]="null">Select</option>
          <option value="1">MSK</option>
          <option value="2">ASKU</option>
          <option value="3">NASK</option>
          <option value="4">UNK</option>
        </select>
            </div>

            <div class='text-danger' *ngIf="newReporterform.get('rptrmiddleName').hasError('bothEmpty')">
                Please enter information in one of the above fields.
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See that you must use `[ngValue]="null"` to asign a null value if you select this options

You can see your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tezebx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)